# Excel VBA for Applications Editor Module Template

Tags: excel, vba, templates

I have a particular header i want to use every time i create a new VBA Module.  Today i copy and paste it from a previous module.
Is there a way to save this as a template and every time i create a new module my template is used?

Example of my header so i know what i have done when i come back to it years later and also when i make revisions or share the module with others:

```
''*************************************************************************************
''Function (fx) or Macro (mcr)
''fx/mcrName = DataSet_to_Table_mcr()
''fxReturns = "This will return ... "
''fxArguments(1) = ""
''fxArguments(2) = ""
''Called by:
''Calls: Fill Colors and Font Color assignments
''Comments: makes a data set into an excel "table" object which has many automated advantages and good astetics for viewing
''
''Keyboard Shortcut:
''Source/Ref:
''Rev History--------------------------------------------------------------------------
''Date              Programmer          Change
''8-Dec-2021        Marcus Kalivoda     created
''9-Dec-2021        Marcus Kalivoda     added more columns and conditional formatting.  ie automated more of what i would do everytime so its already done
''
''*************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I don't think there's any editable "template" for code modules.  If you use any kind of add-in for your VBA programming (eg. I use MZ-tools) and it has a code library you could add your header there and configure a shortcut so you can quickly add it.

Comment: Actually MZ-Tools has an "add headers" feature which can add customized headers to your whole VBA project...

Comment: I will us MZ-Tools and add headers. I do not like MS VBA editor anyways. Thank you!